# LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Tags: c, gcc

Compiling with GCC-11 (-fsanitize=address) is returning the following error:

```
=================================================================
==31634==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 10707 byte(s) in 347 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0xffff7f87432c in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../gcc-11.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x417208 in dup_line (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x417208)
    #2 0x41bca4 in copy_action (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x41bca4)
    #3 0x41d108 in read_grammar (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x41d108)
    #4 0x41f864 in reader (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x41f864)
    #5 0x405ca8 in main (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x405ca8)
    #6 0xffff7f670de0 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20de0)
    #7 0x401468  (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x401468)

...
2 more descriptions of memory leaks 
...

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 12048 byte(s) leaked in 367 allocation(s).
```

I have gone over the different components but I just cannot pinpoint which is causing the memory leak. Any suggestion on what to try would be welcomed.
The modified `copy_action` reads:

```
void
copy_action()
{
    register int c;
    register int i, n;
    int depth;
    int quote;
    char *tag;
    register FILE *f = action_file;
    int a_lineno = lineno;
    char *a_line = dup_line();
    char *a_cptr = a_line + (cptr - line);

    if (last_was_action)
        insert_empty_rule();
    last_was_action = 1;

    fprintf(f, "case %d:\n", nrules - 2);
    if (!lflag)
        fprintf(f, line_format, lineno, input_file_name);
    if (*cptr == '=') ++cptr;

    n = 0;
    for (i = nitems - 1; pitem[i]; --i) ++n;

    depth = 0;
loop:
    c = *cptr;
    if (c == '$')
    {
        if (cptr[1] == '<')
        {
            int d_lineno = lineno;
            char *d_line = dup_line();
            char *d_cptr = d_line + (cptr - line);

            ++cptr;
            tag = get_tag();
            c = *cptr;
            if (c == '$')
            {
                fprintf(f, "yyval.%s", tag);
                ++cptr;
                FREE(d_line);
                goto loop;
            }
            else if (isdigit(c))
            {
                i = get_number();
                if (i > n) dollar_warning(d_lineno, i);
                fprintf(f, "yyvsp[%d].%s", i - n, tag);
                FREE(d_line);
                goto loop;
            }
            else if (c == '-' && isdigit(cptr[1]))
            {
                ++cptr;
                i = -get_number() - n;
                fprintf(f, "yyvsp[%d].%s", i, tag);
                FREE(d_line);
                goto loop;
            }
            else
                dollar_error(d_lineno, d_line, d_cptr);
        }
        else if (cptr[1] == '$')
        {
            if (ntags)
            {
                tag = plhs[nrules]->tag;
                if (tag == 0) untyped_lhs();
                fprintf(f, "yyval.%s", tag);
            }
            else
                fprintf(f, "yyval");
            cptr += 2;
            goto loop;
        }
        else if (isdigit(cptr[1]))
        {
            ++cptr;
            i = get_number();
            if (ntags)
            {
                if (i <= 0 || i > n)
                    unknown_rhs(i);
                tag = pitem[nitems + i - n - 1]->tag;
                if (tag == 0) untyped_rhs(i, pitem[nitems + i - n - 1]->name);
                fprintf(f, "yyvsp[%d].%s", i - n, tag);
            }
            else
            {
                if (i > n)
                    dollar_warning(lineno, i);
                fprintf(f, "yyvsp[%d]", i - n);
            }
            goto loop;
        }
        else if (cptr[1] == '-')
        {
            cptr += 2;
            i = get_number();
            if (ntags)
                unknown_rhs(-i);
            fprintf(f, "yyvsp[%d]", -i - n);
            goto loop;
        }
    }
    if (isalpha(c) || c == '_' || c == '$')
    {
        do
        {
            putc(c, f);
            c = *++cptr;
        } while (isalnum(c) || c == '_' || c == '$');
        goto loop;
    }
    putc(c, f);
    ++cptr;
    switch (c)
    {
    case '\n':
    next_line:
        get_line();
        if (line) goto loop;
        unterminated_action(a_lineno, a_line, a_cptr);

    case ';':
        if (depth > 0) goto loop;
        fprintf(f, "\nbreak;\n");
        return;

    case '{':
        ++depth;
        goto loop;

    case '}':
        if (--depth > 0) goto loop;
        fprintf(f, "\nbreak;\n");
        return;

    case '\'':
    case '"':
        {
            int s_lineno = lineno;
            char *s_line = dup_line();
            char *s_cptr = s_line + (cptr - line - 1);

            quote = c;
            for (;;)
            {
                c = *cptr++;
                putc(c, f);
                if (c == quote)
                {
                    FREE(s_line);
                    goto loop;
                }
                if (c == '\n')
                    unterminated_string(s_lineno, s_line, s_cptr);
                if (c == '\\')
                {
                    c = *cptr++;
                    putc(c, f);
                    if (c == '\n')
                    {
                        get_line();
                        if (line == 0)
                            unterminated_string(s_lineno, s_line, s_cptr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    case '/':
        c = *cptr;
        if (c == '/')
        {
            putc('*', f);
            while ((c = *++cptr) != '\n')
            {
                if (c == '*' && cptr[1] == '/')
                    fprintf(f, "* ");
                else
                    putc(c, f);
            }
            fprintf(f, "*/\n");
            goto next_line;
        }
        if (c == '*')
        {
            int c_lineno = lineno;
            char *c_line = dup_line();
            char *c_cptr = c_line + (cptr - line - 1);

            putc('*', f);
            ++cptr;
            for (;;)
            {
                c = *cptr++;
                putc(c, f);
                if (c == '*' && *cptr == '/')
                {
                    putc('/', f);
                    ++cptr;
                    FREE(c_line);
                    goto loop;
                }
                if (c == '\n')
                {
                    get_line();
                    if (line == 0)
                        unterminated_comment(c_lineno, c_line, c_cptr);
                }
            }
        }
        goto loop;

    default:
        goto loop;
    }
    FREE(a_line)
}
```

Here. I'm still missing something.

Comment: You have to share your code.

Comment: Build with debug symbols turned on and you'll get line numbers.

Comment: The code is huge and available at https://github.com/NCAR/ncl.

Comment: Stephen. I'm looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html but I'm not sure which option you're suggesting. Do you mean including -g?

Comment: @afernandezody: Yes, `-g`.

Comment: In `copy_action`, the `char *a_line = dup_line();` doesn't seem to be matched by a `FREE(a_line)` anywhere?  Nor is it returned or passed out of the function that I can see.

Comment: Hi Nate. Yes, that is what I was looking at. Are you looking at the file in the repository? I tried adding free(a_line) but didn't work, not sure if the capitals make any difference.

Comment: When I add `FREE(a_line)` at the end of the loop in `copy_action` it doesn't build 'nyacc' due to `../../.././ni/src/nyacc/nyacc -d -t ncl.y`    `make[4]: ../../.././ni/src/nyacc/nyacc: Command not found`   `make[4]: *** [Makefile:830: y.tab.h] Error 127` (I'm posting the modified code with the original post)

Comment: `FREE` is [a function-like macro](https://github.com/NCAR/ncl/blob/83ea393b25e15bd850c034c364edc25c0257702b/ni/src/nyacc/defs.h#L102) that just calls `free`, but you might as well use it for consistency.  But like a function, it needs a semicolon at the end of the statement, which you have omitted.  It's unclear if that is the cause of your error; if so there would have been more specific compilation errors further up, that maybe you left out.

Comment: Putting the `FREE(a_line);` at the end of the function won't fix the leak, though, because `copy_action` has `return;` statements at several other places.  You need to make sure that `a_line` gets freed no matter which one of them is taken.  In fact it looks to me like putting it at the end is completely unreachable; every branch of the preceding `switch` ends with either `return` or `goto` (ugh ugh ugh) but never `break`.

Comment: Either that or you decide that 10 KB of leaked memory isn't worth your time to sort through this antique spaghetti.

Comment: Hi Nate. Thanks. Unfortunately one customer needs it so I have no choice but to keep stitching it up until it works. As you mention, I need to go over every potential scenario and free the memory when needed.